# Unlink two layers after a certain time in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions

In After Effects, I want to have a layer (let's call it `Leader`) that moves and another one (let's say `Follower`) that is linked to the first one, so it will have the same movement, but at a specific time (`t`) it should "unlink" from the first layer and stay in that position. I have tried the following:

```
p = thisComp.layer("Leader").transform.position;
t = 1; // Stop following after 1 second
if (time <= t) {
    position = value + (p.value - p.valueAtTime(0));
}
else {
    valueAtTime(t - thisComp.frameDuration);
}
```

But for some reason I don't understand, at time `t`, the `Follower` goes back to its original position instead of staying in the place in which it was "unlinked" from the `Leader`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`valueAtTime` returns the keyframed value of the property, before any expression is applied.

change it to:

```
p = thisComp.layer("Leader").transform.position;
t = 1; // Stop following after 1 second
if (time <= t) {
    value + (p.value - p.valueAtTime(0));
}
else {
    value + (p.value.valueAtTime(t) - p.valueAtTime(0));
}
```

or more simply:

```
p = thisComp.layer("Leader").transform.position;
t = Math.min(time, 1); // time increases until it hits 1, then stays there
value + (p.value.valueAtTime(t) - p.valueAtTime(0));
```

This avoids the `if()` statement which means it should evaluate faster.

Comment: Great! It works. I also like your simpler version, it works jut as good. Just in case, let me point out that it should be `p.valueAtTime(t)` instead of `p.value.valueAtTime(t)`, shouldn't it? Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Interesting. I usually use `[property].valueAtTime()` rather than `[property].value.valueAtTime()`, it seems to work just as well for expressions, but you do need to use the second form for extendscript scripting.